# What is the difference between "is subject to" and "is subjected to"?

Tags: adjectives

I found the following sentence on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection website:

> All persons, baggage, and other merchandise arriving in or leaving the
>   United States **are subject to** inspection and search by CBP officers.

I would like to know whether changing "subject" to "subjected" will change the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

When you are subject to inspection, you may undergo inspection.

When you are subjected to inspection, you do undergo inspection.

Comment: Short and to the point! But I can't think of any similar "adjective / past tense verb form" pairs capable of being differentiated in this way. There's something similar going on in *They were **ready / readied** for inspection* (where to me, ***ready*** could simply imply they *happen* to be available for inspection, where ***readied*** implies someone took steps to ensure they were in a fit state to be inspected), but it's a weak example that doesn't seem quite the same. Can you think of any "better" examples?

Comment: Well, a prospect can be prospected. Before it was prospected, the Klondike was only a prospect.

Comment: [*Subject* (third meaning given under "adjective")](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subject) in this case stems from being *under the authority of* the rules. To *be subjected to* means *to have that authority exercised*. @FumbleFingers actually has quite a good example there (different meanings, but the difference between the two forms is triggering an overlapping set of neurons).

Comment: @Will: One thing I like about ELL/ELU is that when you're looking at what you think is a "one off" quirk of language, it very often turns out other people can rattle off a host of "related" usages (I was particularly struck by the number of related pronunciation changes brought up by [Pronunciation of “have” in “I don't have to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/) over on ELU). So I'm really hoping there might be more (and better) examples than *ready/readied* and *prospect/prospected* for this (to me, quirky) situation.

Comment: I'm giggling away merrily now ... that's a really good question (and answers!). Also seriously impressed if that's *the* Peter Shor commenting :o)

Comment: When something is open to scrutiny, it may be scrutinized. When it is opened to scrutiny, it is being scrutinized.

Comment: @FumbleFingers technically, it's past participle, not past tense.

Comment: @Will: *The local pub is **close** to me* (it's nearby). *The local pub is **closed** to me* (I've been banned). Not really the same thing, though.

Comment: **subordinate to** and **subordinated to** can work the same way.